# Echo a function call from vim command line

Tags: vim

How would I do something like:

```
:echo call MyFunction()
```

so that I can see the result of calling the function?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use something like this:

`:echo Myfunction()`

Comment: @amouravski No probs. You only use `call` when you're not invoking a function in the context of an expression. It's a bit clunky, but I think it's like that so that Vim's scripting language fits the syntax of the ex command line, which it inherited from vi.